# Constructing rationals from countable ordinals

Tags: abstract-algebra, set-theory, ordinals

Take the set of all countable ordinals $\omega_1$. Define $+$ and $\cdot$ by the Hessenberg sum and product. In a similar fashion to the naturals, construct the integers and the rationals from these by taking equivalence classes of ordered pairs. We'll call these the "$\omega_1$ rationals". I have a few questions about this construction:

1. What is the cardinality of the $\omega_1$ rationals? My assumption is that it is $\aleph_1$, as at each step we have only taken pairs of countable ordinals.
2. Are the $\omega_1$ rationals a field?
3. Assuming they are a field, what are its properties? Is it metrically complete? Algebraically closed? If it is neither, how far is it from being metrically complete or algebraically closed?

Comment: What do you mean by "metrically complete"?  With respect to what metric?

Comment: Yes I should have been more specific. I was wondering about the metric given by the absolute value of the difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're exactly right about the cardinality being $\aleph_1$.  This construction does yield a field.  To understand it better, note that by Cantor normal form, the semiring $(\omega_1,+,\cdot)$ can be identified with the set of formal polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{N}$ in variables $x_\alpha$ for $\alpha<\omega_1$, where $x_\alpha$ corresponds to the ordinal $\omega^{\omega^\alpha}$. So, taking formal differences of such things will just give polynomials in the variables $x_\alpha$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$, and then taking formal quotients will give rational functions in the variables with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$.  So this field is a field of rational functions in $\aleph_1$ variables over $\mathbb{Q}$.  In particular, it is very far from being algebraically closed (for instance, it contains no elements algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$ besides the elements of $\mathbb{Q}$ themselves).

(Of course, there is nothing particularly special about $\omega_1$ here.  You could do the same thing for any ordinal $\omega^{\omega^\alpha}$, and you would get a field that is a field of rational functions on variables $x_\beta$ corresponding to $\omega^{\omega^\beta}$ for all $\beta<\alpha$.)

Comment: Since the only elements algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$ are $\mathbb{Q}$ themselves, it seems this field cannot be metrically complete with any metric that extends the metric of $\mathbb{Q}$. This is because rational numbers can converge to algebraic numbers - for instance, you could come up with a Cauchy sequence of rationals that converges to $\sqrt{2}$ in $\mathbb{R}$, and thus would have to converge to a square root of 2 in the $\omega_1$-rationals.